# Tidy.NET - how to view error messages?

Tags: c#, .net, html, tidy

My code uses Tidy.NET to "clean" HTML documents. In some cases, the returned HTML is empty, and I don't know why.

The variable `messages` contains a message collection, and its property `Count` has the value 2 after processing the HTML. Despite knowing that, I don't know how to actually view the error messages.

This is the code:

```
        var tidy = new Tidy();

        var input = new MemoryStream();
        var output = new MemoryStream();

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
        input.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        input.Position = 0;

        var messages = new TidyMessageCollection();

        tidy.Parse(input, output, messages);

        html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
```

What I need to do to know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way. You must iterate through the message collection. Info messages and warnings are also added to the list, so you have to check the `Level` property get only errors (or warnings, whatever you want).

```
foreach (TidyMessage message in messages) 
{
    if (message.Level == MessageLevel.Error) 
    {
        // error handling here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and  it was solved modifying the source code of TidyNet.

In the class `TidyMessageCollection` i was created a public property called `MessageLists` that exposes the protected `InnerLists` with the parse errors:

In `Tidy.TidyMessageCollection`

```
public ArrayList MessageList
{
    get { return InnerList; }
}
```

Now, you can read all the error messages after the `Parse`call outside the Tidy project like this:

```
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();    
TidyMessageCollection tmc = new TidyMessageCollection();
MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream();
MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();

tidy.Parse(input, output, tmc);

//Same code than you
foreach(TidyMessage message in tmc.MessageList)
if (message.Level == MessageLevel.Error) 
{
    // error handling here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue today but not really keen on modifying the source and maintaining a copy of it so here is my solution in one line.

```
var tidyErrors = (from TidyMessage msg in tmc where msg.Level == MessageLevel.Error select msg.Message).ToList();
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Simon